# heroku pg:pull -e does not exclude given models

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-postgres

Using the following command

```
heroku pg:pull HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_XXXX_URL xxxx_development -e "versions" --app xxxx
```

does not exclude versions model from the pull.  This is following the heroku docs.  I'm wondering if anyone has insight on why this doesn't work, or a different/better way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use a *db* option with the *pg* tool. It was Taps that provided the -e/--exclude option but it is no longer relevant having been replaced by [heroku-pg-extras](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-pg-extras). Unfortunately, heroku-pg-extras does not support the -e option at this time.

Comment: I opened a ticket at heroku. They put a deprecation notice at the top of the blog entry (which I won't link to here) that still documented Taps so hopefully others won't waste anymore time on it.